# What technology was used to implement this Rich Web UI?

Tags: web-applications

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238180/what-is-the-best-ui-youve-ever-used), someone mentioned this site which blew me away: http://zoomii.com

Does anyone know how they implemented this rich UI?  At first I thought it was Flash but I don't see the Flash context menu.  Did they hide the context menu somehow or is it some other rich web UI technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript, specifically, [this javascript](http://zoomii.com/vf/091021-164824/books/zoomii.js.m).

Comment: Are you sure this is pure javascript?  Their script shows it is doing something with the ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash object... so I'm wondering if it is indeed Flash.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's javascript. You can clearly see the functions used to manipulate the UI in the link I gave.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has the similar technical via silverlight or javascript:

http://silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/deepzoom/

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/11/20/deep-zoom-without-silverlight.aspx

It is really cool.

Comment: Thanks for the second link, "Deep Zoom without Silverlight".  It clearly demonstrates that you can implement the deep zoom feature using pure javascript.

Comment: It looks like you can implement it via AjaxToolKit.

Answer (score 1):

It's made with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't really minified, in that using Firebug you can read it, though the beginning part is unreadable.  It is 17600 lines of javascript using html for this page.

It would be helpful if they had taken some steps to reduce the file size, but it is a slick example of DHTML.